# Document created with Apache POI is different in Microsoft Word than in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm trying to create docx documents using Apache POI. However, when I open the created documents in Microsoft Word, the result is different from when I open it with LibreOffice Writer. I experienced this behavior with tables and cross references.

I would like to know if it is necessary to make any configuration to save the output format in Microsoft Word format.

For example, the code below creates a docx document containing a table with 2 rows and 2 columns:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableRow;

public class DocWithTable {

    public static final int NUM_ROWS = 2;
    public static final int NUM_COLS = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

        XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
        XWPFTableRow firstRow = table.getRow(0);
        for (int c = 1; c < NUM_COLS; c++) {
            firstRow.addNewTableCell().getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
        }
        for (int r = 1; r < NUM_ROWS; r++) {
            table.createRow();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("file.docx"));
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
        document.close();
    }

}
```

When I open the create document with Microsoft Word, I get the following result:

[image: Document open in Microsoft Word]

When I open it with LibreOffice Writer, I get the following result:

[image: Document open in LibreOffice Writer]

Also, after saving the document in LibreOffice, it is opened as expected in Microsoft Word.

Comment: What version of Apache POI? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm using apache poi 3.17 due to some project limitations. The behavior would be the same with newer versions. The accepted contains the information to solve the problem in apache poi 4.1.0. I added an edit for previous versions.

Comment: @Eduardo: This should not be an edit in my answer but a own answer from you. My answer uses latest stable version. When it comes to `apache poi` the latest stable version always should be used. Else code becomes outdated very fast. And there is no reason for not using the latest stable version, is there?

Comment: @AxelRichter according to Apache POI page: "POI requires Java 8 or newer since version 4.0.1". The JVM that I have to use doesn't support latest stable versions, unfortunately.

Comment: And what are the reasons for using an old outdated JVM? I mean, we are at Java 12 now. JVMs older than Java 8 are ancient.

Comment: There is a huge amount of legacy code that is not supported by recent versions of JVM.

Comment: And this exactly is the reason why IT development fails. There is progress which minimizes security issues but developers do not use that progress because then there is need for changing their good old legacy code. Conservatism sometimes becomes reactionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table cells are all empty. For this the behavior really is different. If no explicit width is set, in `Microsoft Word` all table cells are as width as the content needs, in `LibreOffice Writer` the table width is 100% of usable page width.

Using `apache poi 4.1.0` you could set the table width 100% using [XWPFTable.setWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html#setWidth-java.lang.String-) to make the behavior equal.

in your code:

```
...
XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

table.setWidth("100%");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For `apache poi` versions that do not have method [XWPFTable.setWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html#setWidth-java.lang.String-), the following code can be used:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblWidth;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTblWidth;

    ...
    XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
    CTTblWidth ctTblWidth = table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblW();
    ctTblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.PCT);
    ctTblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(50 * 100)); // 50 times the desired percentage
    ...
```

Comment: @AxelRichter nice suggestion.